# How to implement a custom view engine in ASP.Net MVC that (sorta) isn't file-based?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4, viewengine, custom-view

I've created a fairly generic [view engine](https://github.com/Earlz/EView/) that I created initially without aiming toward ASP.Net MVC. Now though, I think it would be a good idea to have it to where it can at least be easily used by MVC projects. I'm wondering if my project would map well to the ASP.Net MVC style though.

The problem I'm having is that my view engine generates everything at compile-time via T4 templates. This means that everything is statically typed for the most part. Most of MVC seems to be a bit loosely typed however.

So for some view you might have this code generated:

```
class MyView{
  public string Foo{get;set;}
  public int Bar{get;set;}
  public string Render(){
    return "This is my view: "+Foo+(string)Bar;
  }
}
```

And because of how it works, even if there is a views/FooView.html file, it may get processed into a class named `MyView`.

So how exactly is the best way to assign `ViewData` to say `Foo` and `Bar` of MyView? Should I just impose the limitation that you can only use a single field in the views(basically being a `ViewData`) or?

The other major problem I see is that MVC is almost completely file based. When you say `RenderView("MyView",data);` it will look in /views/ for a file named MyView.aspx or whatever(you can change where it looks and the file extension of course). The problem is that `MyView` could have been compiled from a file named `FooView.html`. Should I basically just generate a huge list for every view available with their mappings from class name to filesystem name? Or is there a better way?

Note: Because I generate all the views(and possibly could generate the MVC view engine) from a T4 template, this means I could write huge lists and other extremely tedious or bad code. But I feel like there is a better way than a huge list in this case, and that there will be underlying problems with only keeping a list.

Answer (score 1):

You may extend my T4 based view engine to create your class file from your model, compile it in memory and cache it, and pass your view model to the compiled assembly via reflection.

http://mvct4viewengine.codeplex.com/

Comment: So you have to do it by reflection?

Comment: Also, I was really wanting to do compile the views at compile time. I've already got my view engine made, it just doesn't work with MVC using IView and everything

Comment: Why don't you implement IView on your generated classes? Then inherit VirtualPathProviderViewEngine and create a view engine - mvct4viewengine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/…. And create your compiled view classes instance using reflection, and call the render method of the same. The ViewContext you pass to your concrete IView should contain the view model information